# useradd --non-unique option, when would a duplicate uid be helpful?

Tags: user-accounts, administration

I was reading up on `useradd` and noticed the `-o` (`--non-unique`) option, see man page excerpt below. Can you suggest when a duplicate `uid` would be helpful?

man page excerpt:

```
       -o, --non-unique
           Allow the creation of a user account with a duplicate (non-unique) UID.
           This option is only valid in combination with the -u option.
```

edit: to be clear this seems like a failure of imagination on my part. If you can run `useradd` it seems like you'd have other root-like abilities. I'm wondering if there's a scenario where two users w/the same uid makes sense. (unless I'm reading what the `-o` does wildly wrong.)

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124968/11769, it explains some of the reasons why you would line to use this option.